# Dynamically adding libraries in a jar to your class path

Tags: java, jar, classpath, libraries

So I'm creating a Java project and I want to include a set of libraries in a JAR.

My project is setup like so:

libs/(jars)
Main.java

I'm not sure how to include the jars into my Main.java file without having add the class path in when I compile it:

```
java -cp libs/*;. Main.java
```

Is this anyway to do this dynamically? My Main.java extends a class in one of the jars so I can't load the classes within the Main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set-up your `jar` file classpath at compile time; and [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) explains (in part)

> You specify classes to include in the `Class-Path` header field in the manifest file of an applet or application. The `Class-Path` header takes the following form:
>
> ```
>  Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
> ```

So create a text file for your `Manifest.txt` with your `Class-Path` header and then (again from the linked Oracle Tutorial)

> ```
> jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I like to create a batch file like below in windows

```
@echo off
REM set any custom classpath 
SET classpath=.\;.\properties

REM load all libraries in specific directory
SET libpath=.\lib
FOR %%i IN (%libpath%\*.jar) DO call set classpath=%%classpath%%;%%i

java -cp %classpath% org.test.MyTest
```

Or bash script in unix based operating system

```
#set any custom classpath
classpath=./:./properties

#load all libraries in specified directory
for i in ./lib/*.jar
do
    classpath=$classpath:$i
done
export classpath
java -cp $classpath org.test.MyTest
```